# How to get the records containing minimum unique numbers

Tags: unique, minimum

Can anyone help? 
What is the MySQL query to get

id  | number  | member  | date
11  | 133     | John    | 2020-02-05
9   | 450     | Jason   | 2020-02-07
6   | 10      | Luna    | 2020-02-08

from

id  | number | member | date
1   | 133    | John   | 2020-02-05
2   | 456    | Carl   | 2020-02-07
3   | 450    | Jason  | 2020-02-07
4   | 5      | Kaiser | 2020-02-08
5   | 5      | Liliana| 2020-02-08
6   | 10     | Luna   | 2020-02-08
7   | 20     | Liliana| 2020-02-09
8   | 20     | Luna   | 2020-02-09

where, for each date, it'll select the row with the minimum but the unique number, if it exists.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: The version # is 5.7.22